# Destroy - Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Do not delete that line of mysql. What is the problem ? D

Controller

```php
public function destroy($id) {
    $seriale = Serial::find($id);
    $seriale->delete();
    return redirect()->route('admin.seriale.index');
}
```

View

```html
<form action="{{ route('admin.seriale.destroy',$seriale->id) }}" method="DELETE" role="form">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Sterge Serial</button>
</form>
```

Comment: because You cannot send DELETE request from form

Comment: please , type the code

Answer (score 1):

You can not send DELETE requests easily. Browsers only understand `GET` and `POST`. You have to use a *magic* field to tell Laravel that this is a `DELETE` request:

```html
<form action="{{ route('admin.seriale.destroy',$seriale->id) }}" method="POST" role="form">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<!-- <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE"> -->
{{ method_field('delete') }} <!-- helper functions in laravel are awesome -->
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Sterge Serial</button>
</form>
```

I also added the csrf field to the form, you might need it.

Comment: If you're using `csrf_field`, you could use `{{ method_field('delete') }}` as well for consistency.

Comment: Form Method Spoofing: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#form-method-spoofing   :)

Answer (score 1):

Fix Your form with this notation.

This helper adds special hidden fields to implement DELETE request.

```
{{ Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => ['admin.seriale.destroy', $seriale->id] ]) }}
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Sterge Serial</button>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Read this question and answers: https://laracasts.com/index.php/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-updatedelete-using-forms-and-restful-controllers?page=1

Comment: @AdrianCaragea please mark the question as resolved if this solved your problem.